# how to supress or eliminate zeros after a decimal in 'C'

Tags: c

My program is below, this is for class.
My question is what should I be adding to my program to either stop or eliminate the '.' decimals
and zeros trailing after my answer is printed.

```
// Ch5Pgm7.cpp : Takes a number entered by the user and cubes it.
//Written by: Chris Howard       Sept. 25th 2014.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void cube(double NUM);      // My function that will cube the users input

int main(void)
{
double NUM;
printf("Please enter a number: ");
scanf_s("%lf", &NUM);
cube(NUM);

return 0;
}

void cube(double NUM)
{
NUM = NUM * NUM * NUM;

printf("%lf\n", NUM);
}
```

Comment: Read up on printf format strings: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: ^^ Best answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick to floating point and don't want to use integer, you can use `g` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%g\n", NUM);
```

Comment: @datenwold my understanding is he wants to print `42.1` as `42.1` and `42.0` as `42`.

Comment: @ChrisHoward be aware that big numbers and small numbers are printed using scientific notation with this specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` and the number of decimal spaces you want.

```
printf("%.0lf\n", NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the g specifier to get rid of the decimal `.` and the trailing zeroes

```
printf("%.0g", NUM);
```